# Why can we balance our cycles well when it is moving fast?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What relationship does speed have with balance in the driving of a cycle? Is it related to the principle of a gyroscope?

Comment: Yes, but it is more complicated than that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y4mbT3ozcA

Comment: It's not necessary to move at all, it is ok if one put the bicycle in three cylindrical supports where the moving from the back wheel back cylinder has a connection to the two front cylinders. So the front wheel rotates too and it possible to balance a bicycle. This is used for warm up before a bicycle race :-)

Comment: Oh I see. . . .

Comment: It is more easy to move down on a handhold of a staircase then to balance on it in standstill. So the possibility to move left and right, to stay in balance by the help of little friction seems to be important. This weakens a little bit the theory about the gyroscopic effect.